# How do solve this warning?

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to solve this warning:

> warning: implicit conversion from numeric to char

I want to debug my code and I think that the warning is caused from this line of code:

```
   % Append the hexadecimal representation of the current array element

    line = [line, '0x',lower(dec2hex(hex_array(i,j),2)), ' '];
```

This warning doesn't cause any problem when executing. However, I need to verify my result and this result doesn't let me do that.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are concatenating Numbers (i.e. lower(...)) with Strings (i.e. '0x') in an Array, so Matlab has to convert your numbers in to String Type and warns you that it has done so, you may choose to ignore it if the result is what you want.

If you want to avoid it, use Cell Array:

```
line = {line, '0x',lower(dec2hex(hex_array(i,j),2)), ' '};
```

Or do what @Suever suggested, convert your Numeric Variables to Chars to avoid this warning. i.e.:

```
line = [line, '0x',num2str(lower(dec2hex(hex_array(i,j),2))), ' '];
```

Explanations:

Matlab only allows an Array to be entire Numeric, or entire Chars(i.e. String type), in the cases where it see a String or Char in the Array, it will automatically convert it in to a Char Array.

Comment: You can concatenate strings with `[]`.

Comment: Yea just use `[]` but explicitly convert the number to a char to avoid the warning

Comment: using cell syntax can have unwanted side-effects (e.g. introduce unwanted newlines). In fact, one of the main uses of cell syntax is to introduce newlines in graph labels / titles :p

Comment: @rayryeng yep, I actually started a documentation on this.

Comment: Just pointing out the assumption in the edit that "line" is numeric is probably false. It's more likely to be something like "01: ". And if it isn't, then that's probably not the intended string output, since you would at *least* need a space between the line number and the hex representation

Answer (score 3):

You are concatenating a string with a number. In MATLAB, when you do this, it will [implicitly convert the number to a string](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/valid-combinations-of-unlike-classes.html) since the character array has precedence. To do determine *what* string to use for the number, it uses [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes.

```
['string', 45]
%   string-
```

To avoid the warning, you should explicitly convert your number to a string prior to concatenation. If you want the number *as a string*, use `num2str` or `sprintf` to create it.

```
['string', num2str(45)]
%   string45
```

If you *do* want the ASCII equivalent , just wrap it in a call to `char` to explicitly cast it as a string

```
['string', char(45)]
%   string-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to concatenate a string using [str1, str2, str3] syntax, if one of the objects isn't a string then you get that warning. If "str2" is actually a numerical matrix / scalar, you can get the string representation using num2str(str2).

Having said that, it's probably best to use sprintf to generate that string, e.g.
`s = sprintf("A has a value of %d\n", myval);`